# 実在する "to exist" or "to be real"?

Tags: translation, anime

I'm trying to understand the quote "One Piece **is real**" and have found the following corresponding expression in Japanese:

> ワンピース 実在する

However, this looks more like it means "One Piece **does exist**".

Is the English translation just off and this is the actual meaning, or are there other ways of saying "One Piece is real" in Japanese, which don't mean "One Piece does exist"?

Comment: It's just screen shots form a question I asked long ago. I know it's probably correct but as im not 100 % confident it would be nice if some one with more knowledge in the subject to confirm it... is that really not allowed?

Comment: i fixed it imo--

Comment: Just to give you an idea what kind of question I would expect, I've edited your question. You can undo my edit if you think it doesn't reflect your question well. Even in the current format, it might still be considered off-topic.

Comment: Here's what Google Translate thinks how to say "One Piece is real" in Japanese: 1枚は本物だ. (Caveat: For those who don't read Japanese, read this as "don't trust Google Translate".)

Comment: I think the question could now be answered in its current form as a language question, with comparison to 存在.

Comment: You do know that "ワンピース" is wasei-eigo for "tight fitting sundress"?

Comment: @user312440 actually in the case of the manga, it's not entirely clear what he means it to refer to... it can mean tight-fitting sundress. It can also mean a one-piece swimsuit (http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9_(%E6%9B%96%E6%98%A7%E3%81%95%E5%9B%9E%E9%81%BF))

Comment: @virmaior "In the case of manga"? In the case of real Japanese, I've only heard "ワンピース" used to refer to sundresses worn in the summer. In a beach / pool setting, I can imagine it referring to swimsuits? Never been in such an environment.

Comment: Presumably, the asker is referring to the manga written Eichiro Oda (notice the capitalization in his question and the **the** that you removed when you quoted me)

Comment: @user1720170 what sense of "is real" are you looking for? Like the characters and stuff are a true story?

Comment: @ssb (The) "One Piece" is a rumored thing inside the manga One Piece. I am pretty sure we are talking about whether that thing exists/is real (within the world of the manga) or is fictional (within the world of the manga).

Comment: I was refering to the manga One Piece written by Eichiro Oda!
" (The) "One Piece" is a rumored thing inside the manga One Piece. I am pretty sure we are talking about whether that thing exists/is real (within the world of the manga) or is fictional (within the world of the manga)."  Sums it up perfectyl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this "ワンピースは実在する！" from this anime/manga? It's not related to dresses or swimsuits.

- http://youtu.be/bFb5h9hl9Ig?t=2m3s (at around 2:03)
- http://opwymtk.sakura.ne.jp/mystery/tcotop.html

In this manga, ワンピース is a name of "ultimate treasure" searched by pirates, and very little is known about it. Characters in the manga even do not know whether ワンピース is a touchable object; it may be a name of some magical power, or a city, and it may be just a baseless rumor.

So in this context, "ワンピースは実在する" means "One Piece does exist in reality. It's not a mere legend or rumor." The fansub movie above translates this as "One Piece does exist," which I think is perfectly correct, but I find nothing wrong if you translate this as "One Piece is real."

Besides that context, of course, "(something) is real" cannot always be translated as "実在する". If you want to say something like "This one-piece dress is a real one manufactured in Italy in 1850," use **本物**, not 実在する.

Comment: Perfect answer, exactly what i was looking for. Thanks naruto :)